# I have this error (Gradle sync failed: Cause: org.)

Tags: android-studio

At first:sorry for my bad English , I try to reskin an app by Android studio but I have this error
(Gradle sync failed: Cause: org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.util.ModuleComponentIdentifierImpl.getModu) I tried alot of ways but this error still appear , I tried to change gradle file but there was no thing . I am working on Android studio 2.3.3 , I tried gradle (6.6)(7.3)and 2.3
thank you guys I want your help .

Comment: I think you have more error logs, so show pls

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.